# One to many inserting

Tags: go, sqlboiler

I have two models: `Order` and `OrderItem`. I need to insert order and item of it from same request, e.g.:

```
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "total_price": "200",
    "items": [
        {
            "product_id": 1,
            "quantity": 10
        },
        {
            "product_id": 2,
            "quantity": 5
        },
        {
            "product_id": 3,
            "quantity":3
        }
    ]
}
```

This is Order and OrderItem model

```
=========================== Order ===========================
type Order struct {
    ID          int       `boil:"id" json:"id" toml:"id" yaml:"id"`
    OrderNumber string    `boil:"order_number" json:"order_number" toml:"order_number" yaml:"order_number"`
    OrderDate   time.Time `boil:"order_date" json:"order_date" toml:"order_date" yaml:"order_date"`
    Status      string    `boil:"status" json:"status" toml:"status" yaml:"status"`
    Note        string    `boil:"note" json:"note" toml:"note" yaml:"note"`
    UserID      int       `boil:"user_id" json:"user_id" toml:"user_id" yaml:"user_id"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time `boil:"created_at" json:"created_at" toml:"created_at" yaml:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time `boil:"updated_at" json:"updated_at" toml:"updated_at" yaml:"updated_at"`

    R *orderR `boil:"-" json:"-" toml:"-" yaml:"-"`
    L orderL  `boil:"-" json:"-" toml:"-" yaml:"-"`
}

=========================== OrderItem ===========================
type OrderItem struct {
    ID           int       `boil:"id" json:"id" toml:"id" yaml:"id"`
    OrderID      int       `boil:"order_id" json:"order_id" toml:"order_id" yaml:"order_id"`
    ProductID    int       `boil:"product_id" json:"product_id" toml:"product_id" yaml:"product_id"`
    ProductPrice float64   `boil:"product_price" json:"product_price" toml:"product_price" yaml:"product_price"`
    ProductName  string    `boil:"product_name" json:"product_name" toml:"product_name" yaml:"product_name"`
    Quantity     int       `boil:"quantity" json:"quantity" toml:"quantity" yaml:"quantity"`
    Discount     float64   `boil:"discount" json:"discount" toml:"discount" yaml:"discount"`
    Note         string    `boil:"note" json:"note" toml:"note" yaml:"note"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time `boil:"created_at" json:"created_at" toml:"created_at" yaml:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt    time.Time `boil:"updated_at" json:"updated_at" toml:"updated_at" yaml:"updated_at"`

    R *orderItemR `boil:"-" json:"-" toml:"-" yaml:"-"`
    L orderItemL  `boil:"-" json:"-" toml:"-" yaml:"-"`
}
```

What do people usually do? Is there a way to do this quickly with sqlboiler?

Comment: Is that the input JSON or the final output JSON? Will you please include and label both the inputs and the desired outputs?

Comment: @ZachYoung That is input JSON. Actually, I want: if i send a request with input JSON in body, the program will store the order and order item into database and return "Create order successfully" message.

Answer (score 2):

I think you needn't to do that, you can insert order model and orderItems model in different requests. This solution provide more option than for client. If you need to update or add new order item into the order, you also need this API to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Create some models like

```
type OrderItemInput struct {
    ProductId int `json:"product_id"`
    Quantity  int `json:"quantity"`
}

type OrderInsertInput struct {
    UserID      int        `json:"user_id"`
    TotalPrice  float64    `json:"total_price"`
    Items []OrderItemInput `json:"items"`
}
```

Create new Order by fields `UserId` and `TotalPrice` of OrderInsertInput.

When there was `OrderID`, we will create `OrderItem` with each `OrderItemInput` and the `OrderID`.